# Area of a carousel platform

Tags: geometry

I heard about a problem of finding the area of a carousel platform. A tape could not be stretched across the middle because of the machinery but a tape just tangent to the inner circle formed a cord of the outer circle that measured 70'. The answer said, "Suppose the inner circle had a diameter of zero. Then the cord would, in fact, be a diameter so $\pi*35^2$ is the area," and it works no matter how large the inner circle. I don't understand how the logic can be extended beyond an inner circle of no diameter. How does this work?

Comment: I first heard of this problem in the early 2000's, when it was presented on an episode of the "Car Talk" series run by the Magliozzi brothers on NPR (National Public Radio) out of Boston. They set it as a problem posed to a summer worker at an amusement park who was charged by the boss with painting the deck of the carousel. Wishing to impress the boss, and saving money by not buying too much paint, the worker came up with the solution outlined by Andrei below. Incidentally (and irrelevantly), I heard this episode while riding in my car just a few miles from the Kingston-Poughkeepsie bridge.

Comment: This is reminiscent of the "sneaky" solution to the [hole-in-the sphere puzzle](http://www.puzzles.com/puzzleplayground/HoleInTheSphere/HoleInTheSphere.htm)

Comment: My question was answered to my satisfaction. Why is it now put on hold by amWhy, Adrian Keister, Lord Shark the Unknown, mrtaurho, José Carlos Santos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carousel has an inner radius $r$ and an outer radius $R$. Since the tape is tangent to the inner circle, you form a right angle triangle from the center of the inner circle, to the tangent point om the inner circle, to the intersection with the outer circle. Using Pythagoras' theorem, the length of half of the tape is $$\frac l2=\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$$
The area of the carousel is $$A=\pi R^2-\pi r^2=\pi(R^2-r^2)=\pi\left(\frac l2\right)^2$$

Comment: Thanks, It's so simple, once you know the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. It always helps if you draw a picture first.